# I am working with arrays and need to sort the array. This array keeps showing out of range exceptions

Tags: c#

I have established an array and a large textbox which displays the array.  Basically, you enter a name, 4 quarterly sales figures and it calculates the yearly total.  I am now starting on the sort button.  This would sort given columns numbers from most to least.  I have gotten an if statement that looks like it should work for column five (the total column).  I keep getting an out of range exception and am not sure why.  Any ideas out there?  I am sure this is a simple problem I am not seeing.

```
do {
    swapFlag = false;
    for (n=0; n < lastIndexUsed; n++)
    {
         if (quarters[n, sortCol] < quarters[n+1, sortCol])
         {
             //Column 5
             temp = quarters[n,5];
             quarters[n,5] = quarters[n +1, 3];
             quarters[n +1, 3] = temp;
             //swapflag
             swapFlag = true;
         }
    }
} while (swapFlag);
```

This shows how I get 0-5 for sortCol:

```
if (rbRegion.Checked)
    sortCol = 0;

if (rb1.Checked)
    sortCol = 1;

if (rb2.Checked)
    sortCol = 2;

if (rb3.Checked)
    sortCol = 3;

if (rb4.Checked)
    sortCol = 4;

if (rbTotal.Checked)
    sortCol = 5;
```

Button Variables:

```
int n;
int temp;
int sortCol = 0;
string ntemp;
bool swapFlag;
```

Global Variables

```
int lastIndexUsed = -1;
int[,] quarters = new int[10, 5];
string[] Branch = new string[10];
```

Comment: Lots of `n+1`, and the only conraint on that is `lastIndexUsed`. We'd need to see the life-cycle of lastIndexUsed to even begin to understand this.

Comment: Ok, with `lastIndexUsed = -1` the for loop will never start. Still incomplete code.

Comment: What homework is this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484965/get-last-n-quarters-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quarters` is defined as

```
int[,] quarters = new int[10, 5];
```

since arrays are zero based this gives you index `0...4` on the second dimension but you are trying to access index `5`:

```
temp = quarters[n,5];
```

Comment: I believe if its declared to 5 it creates 0-5.  I have six columns, so 5 would be correct for the last column.  I have noticed a few other errors I made with the zero based system though!

Comment: aka mislabeling column 5, should be column 6.

Comment: @Brandon: That is not correct, only 0 to 4 are valid indexes on the second dimension with your variable declaration

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you could have n = quaters.size - 1, and therefore n + 1 = quaters.size.
So it gets out of array's bound.

Answer (score 0):

I smell the problem is with these:

```
quarters[n+1, sortCol]
quarters[n+1, 3]
```

Make sure `n+1` is a valid index. What if `lastIndexUsed` itself is the maximum valid index? Then `n+1` would cause `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use more instances of `List<int> quartersSortCol0` and use `if (rbRegion.Checked) quartersSortCol0.Sort()` and avoid ineffective constructions like your "while-for" above. While you can use overload of Sort method with custom comparison.